# I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Sony Vaio VGN-T37GP but it runs slow

Tags: screen, intel-graphics, vaio, sony, display-resolution

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 but it runs very slow. Whenever I open any window like "Dash Home" or "Firefox", it takes more time than another computer.

Graphics of my Sony Vaio:- Intel® 852GM/855GM x86/MMX/SSE2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With such an old laptop you should use `Lubuntu`. 1Gb of ram and a 400 MHz CPU is far from recommended hardware parameters.